# Finding recent death records in Germany?

Tags: germany, death-records

I have two persons that died recently in Germany since 1994.  I don't know the city but I have the full name and birthdates.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 6):

There is no single resource for such records from recent decades. These records are kept in local registrar offices (Standesämter) and are subject to regulations according to *Personenstandsgesetz* for at least 30 years after they were created. Afterwards, they might be handed over to a local archive where less strict regulations are in place.

For access to the records at *Standesamt* you have to contact the local office (of the place where the deceased person was living when he/she died) and ask for a copy (fees apply). You will get access if you are

- parent
- offspring or
- partner of the deceased

Comment: You can also try the Standesamt of the birthplace. Recently I found birth certificates which had information on the death too, where death occured somewhere else. I am not sure but it is possible there is some information flowing.

Answer (score 3):

You can find some recent death announcements at https://traueranzeigen.noz.de/

And some 20th century ones at http://familienanzeigen.genealogy.net/

There are a couple more sites like these, but can't remember them now. I think one covered more southern areas.